# DataLakeServiceClient wrong credentials - no error thrown

Tags: python, azure

when using DataLakeServiceClient from python3.5: how do i check if login was successfull?

following sample works OK for correct Credentials but if using wrong credentials it endless loads after calling create_directory. It does not throw any exception.

how to check if Login-Data is OK bevor calling create_directory?

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions
from azure.storage.filedatalake._models import ContentSettings


def initialize_storage_account(storage_account_name, storage_account_key):
    try:  
        global service_client

        service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
            "https", storage_account_name), credential=storage_account_key)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        

        
def create_directory(container_name,dir_name):
    try:
        file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system=container_name)
        
        print(file_system_client)
        
        file_system_client.create_directory(dir_name)
        
        print("Created Directory")
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
     
     
initialize_storage_account("wrongaccountname","a0lyWRONGKEYagAAA==")
create_directory("test_fs","test_dir")
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do i check if login was successfull?

To check if you have provided correct credentials, you will need to perform a network operation. It is recommended that you do a `read` operation like [`get_service_properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake.datalakeserviceclient?view=azure-python#get-service-properties---kwargs-) or try to list file systems.

If the operation is successful, that would mean correct credentials are supplied. If the operation fails, you will need to check the status code in the exception. If the operation fails with `Authorization (403)` error, that would most likely mean an issue with the credentials (there are other reasons as well because of which you can get 403 error).

Comment: i tried list_file_systems and also get_service_properties. Both do not throw any error. they only load like an endless-loop if using wrong credentials

Comment: Hmmm...that's weird. Let me give it a try myself.

Comment: just made some mor checks: it happens, if i provide wrong storage_account_name. If storage_account_name is correct and credentials are wrong it throws exception. but endless loading if wrong storage_account_name. Still a problem because i have to handle all situations and currently it endless-loads

Comment: For some reason I am not able to reproduce this issue. When I provide both wrong account name/key, after a certain time I get the following error message - `<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x11110b050>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known` and after that the program terminates. I ran the application in shell.

Comment: which python version do you use? i use python3. Just added logging and now i see that it seems to call an invalid URL (https://wrongaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/) and retries endlessly (Timeout seems to be very high).

Comment: I too am using python3. After a long wait, I get the exception I mentioned above and the program terminates. Where are you running the code?